# How can I linearize the IFF-THEN constraint with binary and continuous variable?

Tags: constraints, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

I have an optimization problem where

$a_{m,n}\in\{0,1\}$ is a binary variable and $0\le f_{m,n}\le 1$ is a continuous vaiable

I have an Iff-THEN constraint like this

IFF $a_{m,n}=1$, THEN $f_{m,n}>0$

and

IFF $a_{m,n}=0$, THEN $f_{m,n}=0$

How can I linearize them?

I tried as below:

$f>a-1$

$f\le a$

but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that you can't impose strict $>$ constraints. Instead, you'll have to choose a small $\epsilon > 0$ and then require $f \ge \epsilon$. Then these constraints should do the trick:

$$\begin{align}
f & \le Ma \\
f & \ge \epsilon - M(1-a)
\end{align}$$

Here, $M$ is a large constant. You should set it equal to the largest value that $f$ can reasonably take.

The logic is: If $a = 0$, then the first constraint says that $f$ must equal $0$ (and the second constraint has no effect). If $a = 1$, then the second constraint says that $f$ must be greater than or equal to $\epsilon$ (and the first constraint has no effect).

Comment: note that $f$ is upper bounded by 1, so putting $M=1$ does not really give what I want. For some values of $f$, I am getting negative values.

Comment: If $f \le 1$, then putting $M=1$ gives *precisely* what you want, does it not?

Comment: lets take the case $a=0$. the feasible range of $f$ then becomes $\epsilon-1\le f\le0$. The optimizer is taking a value very close to -1.

Comment: But you also have a constraint that says $0 \le f \le 1$, so together these two constraints say that $f=0$, which is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I just forgot to put the other constraint. Yes, I am getting what I want. Thanks a lot.