# How can I linearize this IF-THEN constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Let, $m=1,2,\cdots,M$

$b_{m}$ is a binary variable

$c_{m}$ is a continuous variable

I have an IF-THEN constraint like this

IF $a_{m}=1$, THEN $f_{m}> 0$

IF $a_{m}=0$, THEN $f_{m}=0$

Comment: @Johan Löfberg, could you please help me to linearize this.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243230/how-can-i-linearize-the-iff-then-constraint-with-binary-and-continuous-variable), other than the sum in the RHS of the first "if" condition?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610, there is no other difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar approach as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3243324/663638) can be used. Let $K$ be a sufficiently large constant. Then add constraints:

$$\begin{align}
f_{m,n} & \le Ka_{m,n} \\
f_{m,n} & \ge 0.2\sum_{l=1}^M f_{l,n} - K(1-a_{m,n})
\end{align}$$

(Note that I changed the summation index to $l$ since $m$ is already used in the constraint. I am also using "big-$K$" instead of "big-$M$" since $M$ means something else in your model.)

So: If $a_{m,n}=0$, then $f_{m,n}$ must equal $0$ by the first constraint (and the second constraint has no effect). If $a_{m,n}=1$, then the second constraint prevails, and the first constraint has no effect.

Comment: so, I should have the constraint $0\le f\le 1$ also included, right? And how large $K$ should be in this case?

Comment: You did not specify in the OP that $f \le 1$. In that case, set $K=1$.

Comment: And yes, you should include the constraint $0 \le f\le 1$ in the model as well. My constraints are to be added in addition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.

Comment: It's better to vote to close the problem as a duplicate, than to repeat an answer already given on a duplicate problem.

Comment: That's what I did at first, but I retracted it because I realized the questions are slightly different -- the RHS of the first condition is a constant in the first question but a decision variable in this one. How identical do 2 questions need to be to count as a duplicate?