# How to linearize logical AND constraint in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

I want to implement " if($x_{i,k}=1$ AND $x_{j,k}=1$) then $p[j]\geq p[i]$ " as a linear constraint. Where $x_{i,k}$, $x_{j,k}$ are binary decision variables and p[i], p[j] are integer decision variables. I know that we can implement if-then constraints as [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243230/how-can-i-linearize-the-iff-then-constraint-with-binary-and-continuous-variable). Can someone please help me with this logical AND operation?

Thank you.

Comment: If that answer was satisfactory for you, then $p[j]-p[i]\ge M(x_{i,k}+x_{jk}-2)$ is no worse.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But suppose $x_{i,k}=1$ and $x_{j,k}=0$ then the constraint suggested by you will make $p[j]\geq p[i]-M$ which is conflicting with my original constraint. Can you please suggest some improvement? If both $x_{i,k}$ and $x_{j,k}$ are 1 then and then only I want to make $p[j]>=p[i]$.

Comment: How large can $p[i]$ be?

Comment: I think @fedja's suggestion is correct. You said you want the constraint $p[j] \ge p[i]$ **if** $x_{ik}=x_{jk}=1$. If $x_{ik}=1$ and $x_{jk}=0$ then the constraint is $p[j] \ge p[i] - M$, as you said, but you don't need the constraint in that case -- it is "turned off". Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610, You are correct sir. If $x_{i,k}=1$ and $x_{j,k}=0$ then this constraint should be turned off. Similarly for $x_{i,k}=0$ , $x_{j,k}=1$ and $x_{i,k}=0$ , $x_{j,k}=0$ constraint should be off.

Comment: So fedja ‘s answer is correct, yes?

Comment: @fedja upper limit of p[i] can be 100.

Comment: And what is the lower limit?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 if fedja's constraint is used then for conditions other than $x_{i,k}=1$, $x_{j,k}=1$ it becomes $p[j]\geq p[i]-M$ which I dont want.

Comment: @fedja, lower limit can be zero

Comment: Then take $M=100$ in the formula and have nothing to worry about :-)

Comment: @fedja Its working perfectly. Thank you so much Sir :-)

Comment: I’m still a little unclear about whether @fedja ‘s approach is working for you. But if so, fedja should post as an answer so you can accept it. And if not, you should clarify what’s not working.

Comment: @fedja 's approach is working for me. I am also unclear how is it handling for the cases other than $x_{i,k}=1$ , $x_{j,k}=1$?

Comment: @fedja Is there any way to use this constraint without big-M formulation? Even if it is nonlinear then also it's fine.